# Get string from variable argument function

Tags: c, pointers, dbus

I am trying to pass a double pointer to a variable argument function so that I can store a string in it ("hello world" in my example) and then print it from my main function but its not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void get_value(const char *str,...) {

   va_list valist;

   /* initialize valist for num number of arguments */
   va_start(valist, str);

   /* access all the arguments assigned to valist */
    void *p;
    p = va_arg(valist, void*);

    char *tmp = strdup("hello world");
    *(const char**)p = tmp;

   /* clean memory reserved for valist */
   va_end(valist);

}

int main() {
    const char *t;
    get_value("first", &t);
    printf("%s\n", t);
}
```

I have tried to follow lib sd-bus implementation because it is used a lot in there but so far I havent been able to fix this issue.

My aim is to use this for mocking of an sd bus method for my unittests.

Comment: *Not working* really isn't a technical explanation of what is going wrong. Programmers should be able to do much better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `#include`.

None of the includes you have includes a declaration for `strdup`.  Because of this, the compiler uses the implicit function declaration of a function returning an `int`.  A pointer and an `int` are most likely different sizes on your system.  The mismatch between the implicit declaration and the real declaration result in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The `strdup` function requires that you `#include <string.h>` for the proper declaration.

Also, because you know that the argument to `get_value` is of type `const char **`, you should pass that to `va_arg` instead of `void *` and change the type of `p` to match.

Comment: Nice catch, that's a very sneaky bug that would have probably been missed if OP did not include the `#include` statements at the top.

Comment: Thanks... I am on my mobile using those online C compilers and they didnt show the strdup warning part... works now